# Using mock to test a void method

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I have a class

```
public class NLogRuleComposer : INLogComponentComposer
{
    private LoggingConfiguration _nLogLoggingConfiguration;

    //TODO:  think we need to constructor-inject the logging config 
    public void ComposeComponent(LoggerModel loggerModel
        , LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration
        , string loggerFullName)
    {
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration = nLogLoggingConfiguration;
        var ruleName = loggerFullName;
        var minimumLevel = LogLevel.FromString(loggerModel.level.min_level);
        var maximumLevel = LogLevel.FromString(loggerModel.level.max_level);
        var allTargetsWithLayout = nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.OfType<TargetWithLayout>().ToList();
        var targetWithoutStackTrace = allTargetsWithLayout
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("WithoutStacktrace"));
        var targetWithStackTrace = allTargetsWithLayout.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("WithStacktrace"));
        CreateDefaultLevelFilter(ruleName, maximumLevel.Name, minimumLevel, targetWithoutStackTrace); 
    }

    public void CreateDefaultLevelFilter(string ruleName, string maximumLevelName
        , LogLevel minimumLevel, TargetWithLayout targetWithoutStackTrace)
    {
        var filter = new ConditionBasedFilter();
        filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;
        filter.Condition = "(level <= LogLevel." + maximumLevelName + ")";
        var loggerRule = new LoggingRule(ruleName, targetWithoutStackTrace);
        loggerRule.Filters.Add(filter);
        _nLogLoggingConfiguration.LoggingRules.Add(loggerRule);
    }
```

Now I want to test `CreateDefaultLevelFilter` method, but it is void. I don't know how to test it and test what. Using Mock maybe?

Unfinished code:

```
public class NLogRuleComposerUnitTests
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("MyLoggerName")]
    public void NLogRuleComposer_Should_Create_A_LoggingRule(
        string expectedLogger)
    {
        var nLogRuleComposerMock = new Mock<INLogComponentComposer>();
        var nLogTargetMock = new Mock<TargetWithLayout>();
        nLogRuleComposerMock.Setup(x => x.ComposeComponent(It.IsAny<LoggerModel>()
    , It.IsAny<LoggingConfiguration>()
    , It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Verifiable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be in troubles to test that piece of code without some dependency injection. Creating instances like this

```
var filter = new ConditionBasedFilter();
```

it make impossible to unit test since, as side effect, you're also testing class `ConditionBasedFilter`. Your unit test, ideally, should not test anything except method result or behavior. External dependencies should be mocked.

What I would do:

- Create factories to build instances of all related classes.
- Inject factories interfaces on constructor
- Mock factories to have control about what they return so you can validate, for instance, that correct information is set to `filter`

If you don't have the habit of inject dependencies, you should start making this habit :) Without that, it's impossible to do unit test properly.

This is an example of how you could test `ConditionBasedFilter` properties

```
var conditionBasedFilter = new ConditionBasedFilter();
var conditionBasedFilterFactoryMock = new Mock<IConditionBasedFilterFactory>
var conditionBasedFilterFactoryMock
     .Setup(f => Create())
     .Returns(conditionBasedFilter);
```

Then, you use the factory like this inside your `CreateDefaultLevelFilter` method

```
// this factory is injected on contructor
var filter =  _conditionBasedFilterFactory.Create();
```

At the end of your test, you assert that filter was set with correct values for `Action` and `Condition`. Similar applies for `loggerRule`

Comment: `ConditionBasedFilter` is from NLog library. [See here](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/T_NLog_Filters_ConditionBasedFilter.htm). And I do have a factory for `ComponentComposer`, just not sure how to apply here.

Comment: If you create `ConditionalBaseFilter` with a mocked factory, you could return a instance you control. Let me add and example on my answer